# Dark matter Vs normal matter in a singularity

Tags: black-holes, dark-matter, singularities

Due to "dark matter" not interacting with radiation other than through gravitational forces, could it be possible singularities absorb mostly dark matter and very little "normal" matter?

Comment: It's not really clear yet that dark matter really doesn't interact through other forces. See for instance WIMPs. On a different note, I don't completely understand your question. It feels like you ask whether all singularities purely consist of dark matter. That would definitely be wrong...

Comment: my apologies on the wording of the question. There was not enough character space to word the question the way I would have liked. I was meaning to ask if they could be composed mostly of dark matter due to radiation, all forms of radiation pushing away normal matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the picture below, you can see an accretion disk of normal matter, (it emits light and radiation, as we can see it), around a black hole. I appreciate this is an artists impression, not an actual picture, but we do have a lot of  evidence that normal matter very closely surrounds a black hole, so I can't think of any mechanism why normal matter would change to dark matter due to the creation of a black hole.

[image]

Accretion Disk Around A Black Hole

Also, we do have evidence that at least some black holes have a [Electrical Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charged_black_hole), which dark matter would not produce, as far as I know.

Comment: thank you for your input. I have edited my question closer to what I was wanting to ask. I have seen renditions like this,  understanding a few of the mechanisms involved. As the radiation of forces increase as the event horizon increases, the majority of these forces push normal matter away. The hypothetical dark matter would not be effected letting it "fall in" more efficiently. I was interested in any hypothesis or theorems involved.

Comment: I think @tfb pretty much sums it up, I have never seen any reference linking dark matter and black holes, but the "thing" inside is such a mystery, anything's possible, it's just rather difficult to find out : )

Answer (score 2):

Singularities, if they exist, don't 'consist of' anything: rather they are places (this is not really a word you should use) where something has gone so catastrophically wrong (usually some physically-meaningful quantity has diverged) that the place itself has to be cut out of spacetime.

So no, if they exist, they don't consist of anything.  Fortunately it seems extremely unlikely that they exist, at least to me (speaking as an ex-GR person).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, most properties of matter disappear in a singularity so there is no question of a singularity's composition. All information of the source matter that went into the singularity, except charge and mass as far as I know, are erased. A singularity is its own type of matter.

Comment: thank you, i failed to address change of the laws of physics. It would have been better for me to ask what matter could "fall in" easier.